# Having trouble with getting one pattern printed correctly

Tags: c++

I have to make figures based off of the input value at the start of the program.

It's this section that is giving me a hard time.

```
    for (int i = a; i > 0; i--)//Diagonal line up and to the right
    {
        for (int j = i; j > 0; j--)
        {
            cout << " ";
        }
        cout << "*" << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
```

It is off by one and I have no clue on how to get it corrected.

Input number is 7

Output:

```
-------*
------*
-----*
----*
---*
--*
-*
-
```

What it should print out:

```
------*
-----*
----*
---*
--*
-*
*
```

The dashes are spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just off by 1. Each line should have one less space before the `*`. So subtract 1 from `i` in the loop that prints the spaces.

```
    for (int i = a; i > 0; i--)//Diagonal line up and to the right
    {
        for (int j = i-1; j > 0; j--)
        {
            cout << " ";
        }
        cout << "*" << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simpler way to solve this problem:

```
while(a--)
  std::cout << std::string(a, ' ') << "*\n";
```